# Possible to use more than one Twilio studio flow with the same phone number?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to understand the relationship between phone numbers and studio flows.

Is it one flow per number, so I'd have to pay for a number for each of the flows?

Thanks

Edit: clarification.

Using a pay-as-you-go plan with a deposit and one $1/m phone number.

Comment: Twilio studio flows are not code based and the twilio phone number gets assigned via the dashboard. Not sure what code example could be relevant.

Comment: Do you want to use calls to one number as the entry point to multiple potential flows?

Comment: @AlexBaban I start the flow via an api call. Don’t I have to associate a phone number with the flow for it to work? If I don’t, then would twilit use a random number?

Comment: @philnash for now I’m happy with starting the flow via the API, as in check with course members if they did their weekly practice.

Comment: @AlexBaban thank you! So, the flow I associate with the number is the flow which would be triggered by an SMS to that number (outside of a flow conversation)? And, I can initiate any flow with this same number as I pass it to the API call? (Please post as answer so I can accept the solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to answer this because the information provided by Twilio support, and my experience, contradict the answer I accepted earlier. Thank you to everyone who attempted to answer this.

My confusion was around the possibility to trigger multiple flows from the same number. This is possible, but the SMS replies to the flow messages *drop off* unless the flow is *initiated from the phone number associated with this specific flow in the console*.

So, if I have number-1 and flow-1, I need to associate number-1 with the flow-1 in the number settings. ONLY then will SMS responses to the flow actually go to the flow.

So, the answer to my question is:

**Each flow needs its unique phone number, and the number needs to be associated with the flow in the number settings.**

This requirement ensures that flows "know" the channel they're on, and will not change as the Twilio Studio moves out of beta.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed in the console, you can only configure one flow for a number. When `A MESSAGE COMES IN` will trigger the configured flow.

If you have other flows that are not configured with a number, you can pass your Twilio number as `from` parameter when you trigger the flow via API call. If you don't pass the `from` number you'll get an error.

***Sample Node.js code to trigger the flow via the REST API:***

`+19993335555` is your Twilio number

---

```
const accountSid = 'ACc0966dd96e4d55d26ae72df4d6dc3494';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const TwilioClient = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

TwilioClient.studio
  .flows("FW9d816f0b90d2a10b913868462e339d29")
  .engagements.create({
    to: "+13335557777",
    from: "+19993335555"
  })
  .then(function(engagement) {
    console.log(engagement.sid);
  });
```

***Docs:***
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#rest-api)

Comment: Thank you so much! My confusion was caused by initially configuring the number differently and getting a stock SMS reply when responding via phone to the flow messages. Made me conclude that twilit gets co fused if a number is a part of different modes/flows (which it does, but not for flows). Documentation was not clear for specifically multiple flows per number.

Comment: I will see about getting this added to the docs. [edit] Hmm, actually the docs that you link do explain that you need to include a `to` and `from`. I'll see if we can clarify using multiple numbers with a flow.

Comment: @philnash thank you. It was not easy to create a mental model of the relationship between numbers and flows, especially after replies to my REST initiated flows (with the number I rented) started triggering SMS responses which had nothing to do with the flow. Turned out that I had to know to associate the number with flows... but a number may be associated with only one flow (as a trigger). Very confusing.

Comment: @alex-baban, now I am really confused! I can initiate a flow via rest, but SMS responses do not appear in the flow data unless the "from" phone number's Messaging > A Message Comes In > Studio Flow  is assigned to This-particular-flow. So this means that I need a separate number for each flow?! Because if the "from" number is not assigned to the flow, the sms replies drop off?

Comment: @alex-baban, twilio support just said "Could you please point the number to the "sample" flow or get another number to use with this flow? **As Olga mentioned, each phone number can only be tied to one Studio flow at a time.**